# Scaling problems with responsive Navbar

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar, responsive

I tried to create a responsive navbar for my page by following this [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav.asp).

After resizing the browser i get the correct view, but when i am using a phone to display my page, everything is really small, like in this picture:
[image]

This is the css from the tutorial, just a bit altered:

```
body {margin:0;}
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #373a3c!important;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #555;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="active" onmouseover="hover();" onmouseout="unhover();">
        <a href="./index.html"><img id="logo" src="./images/logo_white.png" /></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="./index.html">Sensoren</a></li>
  <li><a href="./keyServers.html">Schl&uuml;sselserver</a></li>
  <li><a href="./trustSystem.html">Vertrauensgewichtung</a></li>
  <li><a href="./pluginManager.html">Plugin-Manager</a></li>
  <li><a href="./logEvents.html">Log-Events</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="enableBurgerMenu()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Could someone tell me how i could achieve the look on the right on the phone, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this in your `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will ensure that your width is relative to the screen size.

More information here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: You're very welcome. Keep it up with responsive design!

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me proportion vise, i would only increase the `font-size` of all elements by a multiplier of 1.25 (so 15px will become 18px)

Comment: Well, on the PC everything looks much bigger, because the screen is bigger, but the resolution is the same. What i am trying to achieve is, that on a phone everything is as big as it is when i am using a small browser window on a PC, because at the moment, it is way too small to use on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following to your CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.topnav li a {
        font-size: calc(17px * 1.5);
    }
}
```

Basically this overrides the `ul.topnav li a` class you already have in your CSS to have a larger font in mobile.

You could also do the following to change all font sizes:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font-size: calc(17px * 1.5);
    }
}
```